# error while loading CharSequence, AnnotatedElement from Java 1.8 and Scala 2.11

Tags: java, scala

I tried to play with [tmt](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/) from stanford NLP lab. After I installed scala and ran the script, it showed:

```
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
```

java version "1.8.0_05"
scala version: 2.11.2

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The source must be rebuilt with newer Scala to use with Java 8, or use Java 7.  Well, bumping the Scala version is bumpy, so just use Java 7.

Write once, compile anytime.

(The .sbt says 2.9.1, hence the warning on the web site about ancient softwares.)